# PayPal new Rest API return HTTP Status 504

Tags: api, rest, paypal, http-status-code-504

I was testing the new Rest API of PayPal, following their "Make your first call" sample at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/.

Everything when well but since yesterday, I only get HTTP 504 status when trying to get an access_token.

Here's what it return me:

```
Time took: 8208.47ms
Received error: 504
Raw response: An error occurred while processing your request.

Reference #97.864eaad1.1386688164.4daf7d3a
```

I check 10 times my code and everything is ok. What I do not understand is that it was initially working.

Need help please,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me however when trying to get the rest api working for the first time. For me it was the EndPoint in the sdk_config.ini file that didnt have https:// in front of api.paypal.....

Hope this helps someone.